# Configure Google Maps to display travel time by bike?

Tags: google-maps

I move around by bicycle but didn't find how to configure Google Maps so that it displays travel time by bike: "x min ride home" would be more useful to me than "x min drive home".

Does Google Maps supports this, and if yes, how to configure it accordingly?

Comment: it calculates it if in navigation mode and work steepness out - http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/16/google-maps-adds-elevation-profiles-to-bike-routes-to-help-you-avoid-those-steep-hills/

Comment: Thanks. Here's how to do it: Click on Directions, fill the starting point, click on the "..." button, select the bike icon, and lo-and-behold, GM displays the time it takes to get there by bike, including elevation.

Comment: That looks like an answer to your own question so I think you should add it as one.